# ubuntu .syslogs background process which is consuming all CPU

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, command, syslog

I have a real problem with ubuntu VM CPU.
It is a GCP machine, and I have web servers running on these 3 VMs.

TOP command result : 
26271 www-data  20   0  178216   2552    640 S 95.9  0.1   1:22.56 .syslogs

You can see that ".syslogs" is consuming a lot of CPU.
 
I tried reboot many times but still ".syslogs" reappearing after few time.

My environnement :
Server : Ubuntu
Web Server : Apache2
DB : mysql
CMS : Drupal 7

Comment: Hi, this is out of scope for SO, but would be great on https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That is an odd name for a process. Please include the output of `ls -l /proc/26271/exe` ;  There is a chance that someone is running something like a cryptocurrency miner on your system.

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 0 May  4 20:18 /proc/10012/exe -> /var/tmp/.tmp/.syslogs

Comment: That path looks kind of suspicious. Talk to whoever does tech support for your systems to confirm whether that path is legitimate or not. If your system has been broken into, see  [How do I deal with a compromised server](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server).

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not the place but I might just let my answer here since google leads here when you look for the issue:

This just happened to me and the answer is that you have been hacked!

Please check: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=903755 on how to clean a possible backdoor left in some PHP file and here my response on additional steps on how to clean the rest here: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-enterprise-47/troubleshootd-utilizing-high-cpu-and-memory-933116/

I would recommend updating your php and taking other security mesures like not providing your PHP version info and apache version in the server response. Reinstalling the system looks like a very cumbersome none-sense to me...